mysql database connection to xampp install in a different machine
I recently crate a java project in NetBeans with MySQL database in xampp. Local connection is working without any problem. I want to make my project client server. I install xampp on windows server and I change access all granted. I equally change the bind to 0.0.0.0 and also created in inbound port. When using a different machine found on the network, I successfully had access to apache and also phpmyadmin using the server ip address (192.168.0.2). when I open NetBeans on a client machine, upon adding a MYSQL database using JDBC driver, I replace the host with IP address of the windows server which is working on browser but not working in NetBeans.
(https://i.sstatic.net/Lru1Z.png)
here is the error provided to me by netbeans. "
Timeout expired. IDE unable to establish connection. Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment.   You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic."
I want Netbeans to have access to the mysql database found on xampp in the sever machine but don't know what to do.
Need some help

I am receiving an error message

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You think the server is running on the other machine. Check that it actually is using netstat

I am not seeing the server ip address on netstat

Probably not running. This is what I see tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - Of course, that means I can't connect to it from another machine either since it's running on the tcp loopback address [ and that's a good thing ;) ]

There are several reasons why it might not be connecting:

Try pinging between the two computers, if this fails, it may be that the network configuration is not done correctly (if this is the case, try the ping again once the network configuration has been checked), or that the firewall is blocking it, so let's go to the next option.

Another reason may be that the host of the user with whom you are trying to connect from the client is "localhost", what you must do is create another user (it can be created with the same name) whose host is "%" to be able to access remotely.

Finally, if this doesn't work, you will need to check the firewall (both on the server and the client) and create an inbound and outbound rule (both UDP and TCP) for the port that XAMPP for MySQL is using (usually 3306).

Are you setting database connection properly?
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://{serverIp}:{serverPort}/{databaseName}", "{userName}", "{password}";



I tried out the ping and it is working. I equally when on my web browser to access xampp which is on the other machine which is working perfectly. the issue is on NetBeans which is not enabling me to access the MySQL database. (Note that all other connection is working even when using my mobile phone i have access to the xampp but I want NetBeans to access the database.

That's unfortunately not an answer but rather a list of possible troubleshooting steps. This isn't surprising as the op has not provided any error information so you're having to speculate but again, this is not an answer

Here is the error message provided to me by netbeans when testing the connection. "
Timeout expired. IDE unable to establish connection. Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment.   You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic."

I just edited my answer with another possible solution...
